# Null pointer exception occurs while trying to read repeatedly from an InputStream

Tags: java, sockets

The code works fine when I close the client just after sending one instruction. But when I want a client and server connection to persist, so that the client can send multiple instructions to the server one after another, I get a Null pointer exception at the server and the message `java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed` at the client. This happens after the client sends a file to the server and the server successfully receives it. Need help. The error occurs at the **Connection** class code line `switch(clientMsg)`. It seems to me that for some reason the `BufferedReader` `in` goes `null`, but I might be mistaken about that. The code is as follows. Thanks.

Server

```
public class server {
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket socket = null;

public static void print(Object s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}


@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Specify listening port: ");
    Scanner _a = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = _a.nextInt();
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(a);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            print("Connected to " + socket);

            Thread client = new Thread(new Connection(socket));
            client.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            print(e);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Connection

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {

public static void print(Object s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader in = null;

public Connection(Socket client) {
    this.socket = client;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));

        String clientMsg;
        while (true) {
            clientMsg = in.readLine();
            switch (clientMsg) {
            case "1":
                receiveFile(); //method code not included
                break;

            default:
                print("Command not recognized");
                break;
            }
            //in.close();
        }

    }//try run()
    catch (IOException e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

Client

```
public class client {
private static Socket connectToServer;
private static String fileName;
private static BufferedReader keybrdIn;
private static PrintStream msgToServer;

public static void println(Object e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

public static void print(Object e) {
    System.out.print(e);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    try{
        print("Enter IP: ");
        String ip = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();          
        print("Enter port: ");
        int port = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        connectToServer = new Socket(ip, port);
        keybrdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }catch(IOException e) {
        println(e);
    }

    msgToServer = new PrintStream(connectToServer.getOutputStream());

    while (true) {
        try {
            switch(Integer.parseInt(action())) { //action() method code not included
            case 1:
                msgToServer.println("1");
                sendFile();
                break;
            default:
                println("Invalid input");
                break;
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

sendFile()

```
public static void sendFile() throws IOException {
    print("Enter file name: ");
    fileName = keybrdIn.readLine();

    File file = new File(fileName);

    byte[] bytearray = new byte[8192];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    OutputStream os = connectToServer.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
    dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
    int count;
    while ((count = dis.read(bytearray)) > 0){
        dos.write(bytearray, 0, count);
    }
    dis.close();
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();
}
```

receiveFile()

```
public void receiveFile() {
    try {
        int count;

        DataInputStream clientFileStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        String fileName = clientFileStream.readUTF();
        OutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream("_" + fileName);

        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[8192];
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutput);

        System.out.println("Downloading " + fileName + " ...");
        //outToClient().writeBytes("Uploading. Please wait...\n");
        while ((count = clientFileStream.read(mybytearray)) > 0){
            bos.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
        }
        fileOutput.close();
        bos.close();
        clientFileStream.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: On server, you never check incoming message for being null

Comment: I didn't. Please have a look at the above code. But even if I do include an `if (in != null)` statement, the same error occurs.

Comment: Probably something is sent to server after file transfer, that "something" can be figured out if you give your "sendFile()"

Comment: It is not "in" which is null, it is "clientMsg"

Comment: I have now included the `sendFile()` method code above.

Comment: You're closing your output stream after file transfer, so server naturally receives null. Don't close it in sendFile(), close it when your main loop finishes (although it never does)

Comment: And don't forget to check clientMsg for being null on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sendFile(), you close the data output stream which closes your underlying connection's output stream.

According to the documentation of Socket.getOutputStream():

> "Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket".

Comment: na bro! If i dont close `dos` then the server hangs...because the data output stream never stops writing to the server's input stream. The sending never gets finished. If closing the outputstream terminates the corresponding socket, then how else can I accomplish a client server program that persists after a file has been sent?

Comment: @1xQ: This is a problem with your protocol... you should send the file length, so that the server knows how many bytes to expect. (And don't close the output stream)

Comment: @Eyal Schneider: I did that at first, the same problem occurred. However I will do it again now just to see. But the reason I dont do that is because that causes a heap error in case of very large files. I need to transfer files that are above 2GB.

Comment: @1xQ: remember not to close the input stream in receiveFile(), for the same reason.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and the program worked. However, I still get `OutOfMemory error:` `Java heap space` if I try to transfer files larger than 1GB. The program works for smaller files. Is there any way of making this work for large files?

Comment: @1xQ: The OOME isn't clear to me. You are never reading the file fully into memory, so according to the provided code it's not clear why the memory consumption increases when the file size increases.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already closed stream, it will also close socket as well as Eyal mentioned. However, at the moment you close the stream, server side will aware of that and return -1 for read() results.
So, even if you didn't specify file length at beginning, this will generally works well.

However, since you already closed stream, you can't reuse it no matter what. To fix this issue, probably you need to change your Client class so that Client should create socket connection, send files, close socket. That's one lifecycle of opened client socket.

Or maybe in while loop of Client class, 1) take ip, port, and filename to send 2) Create new Thread and provide those information so let thread open connection, send file, close connection 3) and in the meantime, client while() can keep take next ip, port, and filename to send from the user. By doing this, you don't need to make client program wait until file transfer to be completed.

Comment: The input stream returns -1 for end of stream, but BufferedInputStream.readLine() returns null in this case.

Comment: @wonhee: The last part of your answer seems interesting. I will try that out and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the NPE in the server, readLine() returns null at end of stream. You are ignoring it. You should be testing for it immediately after the call, and if null close the socket and exit the read loop.